# Android - create LinearLayout programmatically and initialize id from xml LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

I want to create a scrollable cards view without any libraries.

Each LinearLayout should be a card.
Can I programmatically create a LinearLayout and initialize it with an id from xml LinearLayout?

Like this here (but it does not work):

```
public class LinearLayoutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<ImageContent> images;

private Context context;

private Activity activity;

private int width, height;

public LinearLayoutAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, List<ImageContent> img,

int width, int height) {

this.context = context;

this.activity=activity;

this.images = img;

this.width = width;

this.height = height;

}

@Override

public int getCount() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return images.size();

}

@Override

public Object getItem(int position) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return images.get(position);

}

@Override

public long getItemId(int position) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return 0;

}

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LinearLayout lLayout;


if (convertView != null) {

lLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView;

//lLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageLinearLayout); // this does not work

} else {

lLayout = new LinearLayout(context);


}

return lLayout;

}

}
```

Comment: explain what is not working. what is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get linearlayout from XML, you need to inflate the layout.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                      R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
}

lLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageLinearLayout);
```

Check out this site for better layout reusing with ViewHolder.
http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/